# HAML loses my <td> tag

Tags: html, ruby, haml, handlebars.js

I have following HAML

```
.x-row-tpl
  %tds {{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}
  %td {{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}
  %p {{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}
```

It's rendered into HTML (i mean what i get in browser) as:

```
<div class="x-row-tpl">
  <tds>{{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}</tds>
  {{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}
  <p>{{#parent}}{{name}}{{/parent}}</p>
</div>
```

Why HAML skips `<td>` tag on rendering?

I even tried to wrap it into `:erb`, not it doesn't help. Tried different tag names, even invalid tags (like `<tds>`), everything is working fine, except `<td>`.

Comment: Is the HTML actually *valid*? In other words, is the TD in a TR? IIRC you can't wrap a TD in a TR, so maybe it's just the browser doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: "in browser" is that "view source" or looking at the DOM tree?

Comment: No, it isn't inside <tr>, because it's a Handlebars template. Seems that you're right, it's removed by browser, just tested it with `curl` - and it this <td> tags.

Comment: 'in browser' mean 'in firebug'

Comment: Btw, it's interesting, why Firefox removes <td> but leave invalid tag <tds>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid for the following reasons:

1. Your tag is named `<tds>`, which isn't valid. It should be `<td>`.
2. A `<td>` tag's only valid parent element is a `<tr>`.

When a valid tag element is in an invalid location, the browser is free to remove or move the tag. When an invalid tag name is used, the browser is free to do whatever it wants—AFAIK in most modern browsers it is simply treated as a `<div>`.

Always be sure your final HTML passes the [W3C's HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). If it doesn't, you'll liable to get unexpected behavior.